# Java: Best way to get object from extended sub-class

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract, extends

So, I probably have tought of my program the wrong way, but I can't find how to do what I'm trying to in a pretty way. I also could not find how to search this in Google properly, so sorry if this is already answered. Here is what I have:

I have an abstract class **GameWorld** which will be extended into several different gameWorlds, like **GameAWorld**, **GameBWorld**... I have another abstract class **GameRenderer** which will be responsible for the rendering of these worlds, and will also be extended into **GameARenderer**, **GameBRenderer**...

My issue is, when **GameARenderer** is created (in another class, not GameAWorld), it receives a general GameWorld (which is actually a GameAWorld). I need to get an object from Game**A**World, which is not in GameWorld. Therefore, what I am doing in the GameARenderer now is:

```
Obj chair = ((GameAWorld)world).getChair();
```

because if I simply do world.getA(), without the cast, GameWorld won't have the *getA()* method.

I believe that this may be sounding confusing, so I will try to clarify it later on, if no one understands...

Feel free to suggest changes on my architecture, if no code will solve it.

Comment: As far as I see, what you are doing is ok... have you run into any issues?

Comment: So, there's only one object you need from the world?

Comment: @AchinthaGunasekara No, not any issue atm... I only found out that what I'm doing might be "bad programming".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, the World might have more than 1 object which will be rendered.

Comment: Then to make it flexible couldn't you provide a common interface that includes `getGameObjects()`? Then no matter what world you have it will exist.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I dont really know the concept of that interface, I will try to think about it. What I was previously doing was creating an **Obj List** in GameWorld, and then retrieving this whole List, and rendering each **Obj** using a **for loop**, but that was looking even worse (since I had to pass the List of Generic Objects, which also can be specialized)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils if not too hard, could you provide an example of that interface in work? I cant think of an easy way to retrieve every object. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short but hopefully good enough example I'll try to help you out.

```
public interface Drawable {
    void draw(Graphics g);
}

public class GameWorld {
    List<GameObject> gameObjects;
    List<GameObject> getGameObjects() {...}
}

public class GameAWorld extends GameWorld {...}

public class GameObject implements Drawable {
    // this could be abstract too. Whatever suits your needs.
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) { ... }
}

//inside a renderer
List<GameObject> gameObjects = gameWorld.getGameObjects();
for (GameObject go : gameObjects)
    go.draw(g);
```

That's the way I'd do it. Be advised I slapped that together quick-like; it might not be 100% correct but you should get the point.

Comment: Thanks ChiefTwoPencils! That was what I was kind of doing earlier, but this looks better. I will think about your solution in comparison to what I'm doing atm and see what works better.

Comment: Good luck. Report back with your findings. @GuiFGDeo

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I was thinking about your approach, and realized that there is no *draw()* method on my GameObjects. It does not know how to draw itself... The GameRenderer was the one who did. I believe that your approach is better than doing my **cast**. I will try to implement it, but will also have to implement the **draw** method on each object (which seems to be even better). I will see how it goes and accept your answer if it turns out ok :D

Comment: So, now I'm banging my head against another problem. The current GameARenderer (which is responsible for drawing the GameObject) has a Shape which is used to draw the object. In order for the Object to draw itself, it would need to receive this Shape, therefore the method would be *draw(Shape s)*. However, in some cases, instead of using the *Shape*, the object would use a Batch, resulting in *draw(Batch b)*. How do I allow these changes on my superclass GameObject?

Comment: I would put those aspects in the `Drawable`. The view (renderer) shouldn't really need to know about the individual shapes or batches that are needed to draw it. That won't scale very well if you have lots of objects to render of different shapes and such. That's why you just pass the graphics to the object. Because you're having this problem keeping it generic is a sign your design may not be the best approach. @GuiFGDeo

Comment: OK, then I believe that I would create the Shape/Batcher inside the Drawable. Just one minor concern... Wouldnt it be too heavy (I was thinking about a mobile app) if each GameObject had its own Shape/Batcher?

Comment: I may have to see your design to help with that. Don't they all need their own shape or batch; or are these very simple shapes that you're reusing; and how is that done? @GuiFGDeo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93120/discussion-between-guifgdeo-and-chieftwopencils).